# Android How to define a many to many SQLite query

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have two tables, the first contains the Category, Menu items and the Quantity I sold in a store. So for example

```
Table A
CATEGORY X MENU          X QUANTITY
Chicken  x ChickenStew   x 7 
Beef     x Stew          x 10
Fish     x FishStew      x 8 
Chicken  X Chicken Stew  x 5
Fish     X Fish Stew     x 2
```

I have a second table which defines the Bill of material for each menu item like this

```
table B
MENU          X  BILL_OF_MATERIAL
Chicken Stew  x  chicken
Chicken Stew  x  sauce
Chicken Stew  x  salt
```

I want an SQLite query that will copy each category, menu and Quantity in the first table A into a third table C and match the corresponding bill of material from table B. So if I have one menu item and Quantity in table A which has 11 items in its Bill of material in table B. When i run the query it will copy into table C 11 items, which will be the menu item, its quantity and 11 row with the BOM

```
Table C
    Category x MenuItem X Quantity x Bill of Material
```

this is what I had but it doesnt seem to work

```
UPDATE OE_Sales_Activity SET RawMatType = (SELECT RawMaterialPortion FROM Define_Raw_Material_Portioning where Define_Raw_Material_Portioning.MenuItemPortion =OE_Sales_Activity.FP_SKU)
```

Comment: Why are you trying UPDATE? Don't you want to insert new rows to the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following may be along the lines of what you want (according to

> *I want an SQLite query that will copy each category, menu and Quantity in the first table A into a third table C and match the
>   corresponding bill of material from table B.*

):-

```
INSERT INTO tablec 
SELECT category, tablea.menu, quantity, bill_of_material
FROM tablea JOIN tableb on tableb.menu = tablea.menu;
```

- note table names as per your example data.

Based upon a slightly amended set of example data (more data in tableb) consider the following :-

```
-- DROP tables (note tableb as it references table should be dropped first)
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tableb;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablea;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablec;
-- Create the tables
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablea (category TEXT, menu TEXT UNIQUE, quantity INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableb (menu TEXT REFERENCES tablea(menu), bill_of_material);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablec (category, menu, quatity, bom);
-- Populate the tables, tablea and tableb
INSERT INTO tablea VALUES
    ('Chicken','ChickenStew',7),('Beef','Stew',10),('Fish','FishStew',8),('Chicken','Chicken Stew',5),('Fish','Fish Stew',2);
;
INSERT INTO tableb VALUES
    ('Chicken Stew','chicken'),('Chicken Stew','sauce'),('Chicken Stew','salt'),
    ('ChickenStew','chicken legs'),('ChickenStew','chicken stock'),('ChickenStew','Leek'),
    ('FishStew','Fish'),('FishStew','fish stock'),('FishStew','onion')
;
SELECT * FROM tablea; -- <<<<<<<<<< result 1
SELECT * FROM tableb; --<<<<<<<<<< result 2
DELETE FROM tablec; -- <<<<<<<<<< Clear tablec >>>>>>>>>
-- populate tablec according to tablea and tableb
INSERT INTO tablec 
SELECT category, tablea.menu, quantity, bill_of_material
FROM tablea JOIN tableb on tableb.menu = tablea.menu;

SELECT * FROM tablec; -- <<<<<<<<<< result 3
```

The above populates tablea to be :-

[image]

and tableb (with additional data for a more comprehensive example) to be :-

[image]

**and tablec gets populated according to tablea and tablec to be  :-**

[image]

- Note that to take advantage of the Foreign Key (the REFERENCES) you have to specifically turn Foreign Key support on.

  - The above will still work without foreigns key support turned on. However, a row could be added to tableb where the **menu** column (e.g FishBroth) is not a menu item in tablea.

I don't believe that you want to UPDATE, at least not without a suitable WHERE clause, otherwise ALL ROWS will be updated setting the **RawMatType** column of all rows to the same value.

Comment: It worked. Many thanks. Much appreciated, the detailed response and the time given to help me find a solution.